# Safest way to mount Bench Grinder

Tags: safety, bench, grinder

I have very little room to work with and have decided some things I am going to end up sticking where there is room, but would it be any less safe, if suppose I wanted it on a stand alone platform that I've cemented the mount to a reasonable depth, instead of an actual "bench"? I don't see why it would matter but again I don't see a lot things that are common sense to others. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am satisfied with the bench location of my *bench* grinder, I just need to be diligent about keeping free space around it. One thing to remember is sparks; place in an area free of combustibles/flammables and where sparks won't damage anything.

Comment: Yeah thanks I was thinking about that, but have all flammables and chemicals stored away from the workspace,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often seen grinders mounted on a pedestal, as long as they don’t move it gives more access for odd shaped work pieces.

Comment: Ok thanks Mike. I bought it because it was on sale not because I have an actual need for one, and I can see a lot potential damage if I'm careless